# CoreData Holds data after delete

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsnumber

I using a Core Data with 2 entities One is my archive, have reference for image, name and `NSNumber` the second Entity is mi numeric balance.

In the Archive view i can load Archive entity in to a UITable View, if i tap on my cell i have the perfect detail and my button to set the Card.

In the detail I've the Delete button, this have a function to delete a single card and in to Balance entity change the numeric value.

If i try to delete is working well and the Balance load good the new value, but is i add new card, my balance add a new value plus the last value erased:

Start App add my card with Name, Image and value (10), Balance show 1 card, total 10, is ok.

Go to my archive select my card and Delete, now i have empty archive, and my Balance showing 0 card and 0 value, now if i add other card exaple value 10, my balance sowing 2card and 20value.

this is the code using to delete:

```
- (IBAction)delete:(id)sender {

    NSError *error;

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    [context deleteObject:loadA[_currentRecord]];

//image remover from documents folder//
    NSString *imageRemover = [[self docsDir]stringByAppendingPathComponent:nomeSc.text];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", imageRemover] error:&error];

//----------------------------------//
    if (![context save:&error]){

        NSLog(@"Save Error, please retry: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self refreshBalance];

    _currentRecord =-1;

}

- (void)refreshBalance:(id)sender {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (_currentRecord <= -1) {

        modifyA = loadA[_currentRecord];
        modifyB = loadB[currentBalance];

    }

        int oldBet = [betOld.text intValue];
        int cardBetting = [modifyB.totalCards intValue];

        int amauntBet = [blDetail[0] intValue];



        modifyB.totBet = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:amauntBet - oldBet];
        modifyB.totCards = [NSNumber numberWithInt:cardBetting -1];
    }


    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Errore durante il salvataggio: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    _currentRecord = -1;
    _currentBalance = -1;

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

***************THIS IS A FUNCTION TO SAVE**********************************

```
- (IBAction)onSave:(id)sender{

    NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imageName = self.name.text;
    NSString* foofile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", imageName]];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foofile];

    if (fileExists == YES){

        NSString *titolo = @"Warning";
        NSString *messaggio = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your name ( %@ ) exist, please changeit!", imageName];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    } else


    if (nomeGiocata.text.length == 0 || importoGiocato.text.length == 0 ) {

        NSString *titolo = @"Warning";
        NSString *messaggio = @"There are empty fileds!";

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    } else {

        NSString *imageName = self.nomeGiocata.text;
        NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString * basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
        UIImage * imageToSave = self.imageViewPick.image;
        NSData * binaryImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToSave, 1.0);
        [binaryImageData writeToFile:[basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", imageName]] atomically:YES];

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        [self.managedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];


        newScheda = [NSEntityDescription
                    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Archive"
                    inManagedObjectContext:context];

        newScheda.immagine = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", imageName];
        newScheda.nome = nomeGiocata.text;

        int bet = [importoGiocato.text intValue];
        newScheda.giocata = [NSNumber numberWithInt:giocata];

        addSched = balance[currentRecord];

        int insert = [addSched.totScommesso intValue];
        addSched.totScommesso = [NSNumber numberWithInt:insert + bet];

        int aggiungiSched = [addSched.totSchedGiocate intValue];
        addSched.totSchedGiocate = [NSNumber numberWithInt:aggiungiSched + 1];

        int balance = [addSched.totBilancio intValue];
        addSched.totBilancio = [NSNumber numberWithInt:balance + giocata];


        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error during the process: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        NSString *titolo = @“MyApp";
        NSString *messaggio = @"Saved!";

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    [self clearFields];

}
```

How can empty a cache when i delete my Record? or have other idea?

Comment: can you also show code where you add cards ?

Comment: Could you please explain better your problem and format your question? It's not clear what you're asking. In addition the title should be changed. Thanks.

Comment: Is Simple when i delete the Card, is like to delete the record only on Archive Entity and non in to Balance Entity, if i delete one card with value 10 and add for exaple other card with value 20, the Balance result is 30 and not 20